# Devise returning NoMethodError (undefined method `new_user_session_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, twitter, omniauth

I just upgraded to Devise 2.0 from Devise 1.5.1.

```
Using omniauth (1.0.3) 
Using omniauth-oauth (1.0.1) 
Using omniauth-twitter (0.0.8)
```

I'm using this for twitter authentication. I keep getting:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `new_user_session_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x00000009b57c10>
```

My routes look like:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'sessions', :omniauth_callbacks => 'authentications' }, :skip => [:sessions] do
    get 'sign-out' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end
```

This error shows up in production. Everything works on development. I am also running on Heroku, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Could you paste your `rake routes`?

Comment: `rake routes | grep session`, or do you need something more in routes?

Answer (score 3):

You've added `session` to skip, which means devise wont create those routes. If you want to customise your urls, follow the documentation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes).

In your case, it would be

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]
as :user do
  get 'sign-in' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  post 'sign-in' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
  delete 'sign-out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

Comment: Why does the problem not happen in development though? Second, why and where is Devise calling `new_user_session_path`, if I explicitly told it to skip it?

Comment: I dont know why id doesnt happen in development, but you didnt tell devise to skip 'calling' it, you only told it to skip 'creating' it.

Comment: User sign in should happen with omniauth_callbacks not new_user_session though

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem so i created a custom rout and it worked for me

```
match '/users/sign_in' => "devise/sessions#create", :as => :create_user_session
```

I hope this works for you. You can customise it to suit your need

Comment: Why does the problem not happen in development though?